# Dynamic change language in yandex maps

Tags: yandex-api, yandex-maps

I need to change language in yandex maps, but I don't know how do it!
Language in yandex maps can be changed static in script tag.

```
<script src="http://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&load=package.full"></script>
```

But I need to change language in running application.

For example, google maps have loader:

**HTML Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

**JavaScript Code**

```
google.load('maps', '3.7', {
    'other_params' : 'sensor=true&language=' + langCode,
    'callback' : deviceReadyFunc
});
```

In yandex maps I have not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solve this problem with localStorage and dynamic adding script-tag.

**JavaScript Code**

```
var script=document.createElement('script');
if (GLOBAL_LANGUAGE === 'en') {
    script.src = 'http://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=en-US&load=package.full';
} else {
    script.src = 'http://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru-RU&load=package.full';
}
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(script);
script.onload = function() {
    ymaps.ready(init);
};
```

In running application after change localStorage variable `GLOBAL_LANGUAGE` I call `reloadApp()` method:

```
reloadApp: function() {
    location.href = '#home';
    location.reload();
}
```

After this actions yandex maps change language in running application.